# WordPress WooCommerce Staging Site Database Sync

Tags: mysql, sql-server, wordpress, woocommerce

I manage a WordPress WooCommerce site which has a couple mishaps in the recent past. There is no staging environment setup which would have prevented the mishaps and is not trying to set one up.

I have researched many WordPress DB Sync plugins, however, not many states they work well with WooCommerce. The issue is on my side, the product team can update `add/remove` products, categories, blog posts, etc. at any given time, they have no set time-frame window which updates the site.

I need a way that I can sync menu structures, products, and all, blog posts, etc. with the production environment. I need to sync, because while the product team is working new orders come in and comments are posted, etc.

Is there any easy way to set up a staging site that will accomplish this?

Daily, I work with MSSQL and write a lot of SQL, so I thought I could write a sync script for `moving/syncing` data to production, however, the command I needed `"MERGE"` is not available in MySQL. Or, is there a way WordPress can run on MSSQL?

Any ideas?

Comment: do you really need the newest orders etc on your development enviroment? why not make your changes, and copy those changes to live, instead of pushing everything?

Comment: No I don’t, I just can’t do a mysqldump of staging and overwrite production.

Comment: Main Problem is that some WooCommerce stuff is saved in wp_posts … so moving a dump is not a option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion, you can use default WooCommerce Import and Export available on the Product page on the top side.

It is the best option to save all database in Raw format and easily restore as per your need.
[image]